# How to return a list of pairs of strings from a large matrix that mutually satisfy a maximum stringdistance criterion?

Tags: r, stringdist

I am trying to make a way of presenting human-input words in a way that makes their groupings more easily recognisable as referring to the same thing. Essentially a spellchecker. I have gotten as far as making a large matrix (the actual one is 250 * 250 ish). The code for this matrix is identical to the reproducible example given below. (I have populated this with a random word generator, the actual values make much more sense but are confidential)

```
strings <- c("domineering","curl","axiomatic","root","gratis","secretary","lopsided","cumbersome","oval","mighty","thaw","troubled","furniture","round","soak","callous","melted","wealthy","sweltering","verdant","fence","eyes","ugliest","card","quickest","harm","brake","alarm","report","glue","eyes","hollow","quince","pack","twig","knot")

matrix <- stringdistmatrix(strings, strings, useNames = TRUE)
```

Now I want to create a new table with two variables, the first column must contain pairs of elements of 'strings' that satisfy the condition that their string-distance was lower than some number lets say for this example (stringdist<7, nonzero), the second column must contain the stringdist. Also the table should not show the reflection of the results present in the matrix e.g. (oval, curl: 3), (curl, oval: 3).

I've got a feeling that this will require an `apply` function of some sort but I haven't a clue.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution based in the tidyverse should do the trick.

Please note that the last line is in there to make for an easy view of the result. I would not think it to be necessary for your purposes. If you do want to keep it, I would advise to incorporate it in the initial making of 'pair'.

```
library(stringdist)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

matrix %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(X = colnames(.), .before = 1) %>%
  pivot_longer(-X) %>%
  filter(value %in% 1:7) %>%
  transmute(pair = map2(X, name, ~ sort(c(.x, .y))),
            stringDist = value) %>%
  distinct(pair, stringDist) %>%
  mutate(pair = map_chr(pair, ~ str_c(., collapse = '_')))

# A tibble: 451 x 2
#   pair                   stringDist
#   <chr>                       <dbl>
# 1 domineering_sweltering          6
# 2 curl_root                       4
# 3 curl_gratis                     6
# 4 curl_secretary                  7
# 5 cumbersome_curl                 7
# 6 curl_oval                       3
# 7 curl_mighty                     6
# 8 curl_thaw                       4
# 9 curl_troubled                   6
# 10 curl_furniture                 7
```

Comment: Thanks, that solution is great. Ive done a bit more research and found people using the ```melt``` function in ```reshape2```. This can get very close with only two lines of code e.g. :   ```X <- melt(X) ;  X <- X[X$value <= 4 & X$value != 0,]``` The problem is that this still includes the reflection of the string-pairs, do you have any ideas how to fix that in this method?

Comment: You are very welcome @Jose_harkhan. I'm glad that it solves your problem. I'm not familiar with the use of ```melt()```. For what it is worth: A lot of the work done by the solution I posted is done to remove the reflections.

Comment: so I can see! if you could shed any light on how the removal of the reflections works that would be much appreciated. Also I wonder if there is anything that can be done to the matrix that makes it triangular, or fills in one triangle with zeros prior to dyplr (etc) manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

This also does the job

```
matrix[lower.tri(matrix)] <- 0
matrix_melt <- melt(matrix)
matrix_melt %>%
    filter(value %in% 1:7)
```